# Replacing a looped http call with Promise.all

Tags: javascript, axios, es6-promise

I am trying to replace the loop that send out http requests using Axios. http is an Axios object and returns a promise. I want to change the code so that I use Promises.all() instead of a loop. I am trying to create a Promise, push into an array and then pass on to Promises.all. I only get empty arrays in my promises array.

I would appreciate any pointers on what I am doing wrong.

```
// Converting this 
responseData = [];
for (const record of response.records) {
    let response = await http.get('/records/' + record.id);
    responseData.push(response.data.data);
}




    // I am trying to convert to this ..
      let promises = [];
      for (const record of response.data.data) {
          let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
             let response = http.get('/records/' + record.id)
                     .then(response => {
                       return response.json();
                     })
                     .then(resp => {
                       // console.log(resp.data.data);
                         //return resp.data.data
                         resolve(resp.data.data);
                     });
    
             return response;
    
          });
          promises.push(promise);
      }
    
      Promise.all(promises).then(records);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure of whether response.json() is required, and where the .records and .data.data should go ... but this might work:

```
  const promises = [];
  for (const record of response.records) {
      promises.push(
          http.get('/records/' + record.id)
              .then(response => response.json())    //maybe?
              .then(response => response.data.data)
      )
  }
  Promise.all(promises).then(records => { /* do something */ } );
```

or use map:

```
const promises = response.records.map(record => 
     http.get('/records/' + record.id)
         .then(response => response.json())    //maybe?
         .then(response => response.data.data)
)
Promise.all(promises).then(responseData => {/* do something */} );
```

Comment: Thanks mate. The second one worked for me. So, when does the actual http.get() happen in the first map or the Promise.all() ?

Comment: It happens somewhere between the two. The Promise.all is the point by which all of the http.gets have finished and you hopefully have your answers, and that's mostly what you care about. Each one starts when http.get is called, or strictly speaking it gets chucked on the event loop when http.get is called, to execute when the event loop gets to it (and the subsequent .thens to execute after this). The benefit of this is that they can execute in parallel ("non-blocking IO" and all that), and you can ask one to start before the other has returned, for which we use map here.